# Unable to convert bytes to hex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial, python-bytearray

I have a serial device (loadcell) connected to pc which is constantly sending data in a fixed format. It has 2 stop bits (0x40 and 0x0b). I am trying to read until 1 stop bit so I can start reading the message from the start. The problem is the code never exits the while loop. I tried many ways to convert the bytes I am receiving from the serial port into hex but I can not manage to get out of the while loop.
I NEED to use hex here because `0x0b` value doesn't have any visual (doesn't represent any character). I can not give that input from keyboard!!

```
loadcell.reset_input_buffer()
some_hex_val = 0x00
def read_thrust():
    global some_hex_val
    while some_hex_val != 0x0b or some_hex_val != 0x40:
        some_hex_val = loadcell.read().hex()
    print('Exited while')

read_thrust()
```

How do I read each byte as hex?

Update:

The `.hex()` method doesn't return anything!!? I am reading from serial port in `bytes` but using the `.hex()` method on it returns `None` i guess (because its not printing anything?)
[Printing out the types just to be sure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEO2Q.png)

Comment: `or` should be `and`

Comment: `.hex()` returns a *string* of the hexadecimal digits and isn't what you want here.  It is unclear what `loadcell` is but you probably want `some_hex_val = loadcell.read(1)` to extract one byte from the stream and compare with `while some_hex_val not in b'\x0b\x40':`.  Adding a `print(some_hex_val)` in the loop would help debug.